# Silverlight 5. ControlStoryboardAction not supported in VS 2012?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, expression-blend, silverlight-5.0

Have a wierd problem with a Silverlight 5 application made in Visual studi0 2012.

Problem:

Using Expression Blend Preview for Silverlight 5 i have succesfully added a storyboard to a view, and a **ControlStoryboardAction** to trigger the storyboard on grid load.
This will render fine in Expression Blend, but looking at the xaml in VS2012 it will fail with the following error:

```
The type 'ControlStoryboardAction' from assembly 'Microsoft.Expression.Interactions' is built with an older version of the Blend SDK, and is not supported in a Silverlight 5 project.
```

The application builds and runs fine in the browser, i.e. the storyboard is triggered, but it is still quite annoying that VS2012 will throw an error.

I see that it seems to be a assembly version problem, but everything is setup for Silverlight 5.

Below is the xaml in question:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger>
            <ei:ControlStoryboardAction x:Name="GridLoadedTriggerEvent" Storyboard="{StaticResource StoryBoardWindowFadeIn}"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="60" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    ...Excluded text...
</Grid>
```

The problem lies with the use of:

```
<ei:ControlStoryboardAction x:Name="GridLoadedTriggerEvent" Storyboard="{StaticResource WindowFadeIn}"/>
```

From the namespace: `xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions"`

Does anyone have a solution or an explanation to why there seems to be this version problem.

Thanks

Comment: If you haven't already done so, I would shoot this as a bug over to Microsoft Connect. http://connect.microsoft.com/

Comment: Still and issue for us - http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/764733/visual-studio-2012-bug-the-type-xxx-from-assembly-yyy-is-built-with-an-older-version-of-the-blend-sdk-and-is-not-supported-in-a-silverlight-5-project

Answer (score 1):

I was unable to reproduce this exact issue (Works fine in Blend Preview, able to run and build fine in the browser, but display a XAML error in VS 2012), but I did get a similar error in VS 2012 when I referenced the `\Silverlight\v4.0\` version of `Microsoft.Expression.Interactions.dll` in conjunction with the `\Silverlight\v5.0\` version of `System.Windows.Interactivity.dll`.

So can you verify that these two DLL's:

> `Microsoft.Expression.Interactions.dll`
>
> `System.Windows.Interactivity.dll`

are both referencing the Blend Silverlight 5.0 assemblies located at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Expression\Blend\Silverlight\v5.0\Libraries`.

If they are not, try removing and re-adding these items from the v5.0 version.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem--possibly the same one--and my issue was with `System.Windows.Interactivity.dll`.

We are using [MVVM Light](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/) in my project, and apparently it supplies its own version `System.Windows.Interactivity.dll`.  From what I could tell, the version information was correct, but the VS2012 error was there anyway.

Once I removed and re-added the reference (same location as Scott Koland's Nov 16 note), everything cleared up & now works properly.